# Swift googlemaps ZOOM delegate(listener)

Tags: swift, google-maps, zooming

I am trying to achieve func for detecting zoom level changed in GoogleMaps.

I tried this one but not working as expected

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition) {
     print(position.zoom)
     if(position.zoom != self.startZoomPosition){
          self.zoomIsActive = true
     }
}
```